# CSS, box that scrolls but doesn't disappear

Tags: html, css

I am not sure if the wording is right. I have Googled my different terms. In plain English I want a:

**box that scrolls but doesn't disappear.**

I am trying to achieve boxes similar to Linkedin's side boxes. They scroll with the page but stop scrolling and never disappear.

A mix of: `position:fixed` and `position:absolute`?

I have other boxes over the box is question, positioned in the exact same area as a side box.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with raw CSS, though it **is** possible if you use JavaScript. All you need to do is work out how far down the page the user is, and add content every time they scroll a certain number of pixels.

This can be achieved very easily with jQuery. You can bind to the `$(window).scroll()` function, and check the height with `$(window).scrollTop()`. Then simply append some new content with `.append()`.

In the following example, `$(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100` checks when the user is 100 pixels away from reaching the end of the content. New content is then appended, and the scrollbar grows in length.

Because it checks against the **height** of the document, every time the end of the **new** content is reached, the loop will trigger again, and even more content will get created. Thus, the following provides a truly infinite scroll:

```js
/* Initial content */
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  $("#scroll").append($("<div class='original-content'>Original content</div>"));
}

/* Bonus content */
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 100) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      $("#scroll").append($("<div class='new-content'>New content</div>"));
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="scroll"></div>
```

Hope this helps! :)